# I'm trying to scrape a specific div with an id on a page

Tags: php, domdocument, web-scraping

I want to scrape the contents of a page, well really just a single div from that page, and display it to the user inside of a small div on a webpage.  I just need a piece of info from a carfax page that needs user credentials so I can't post the exact code but I tried using google.com and have the same problem so the solution should cross over.

Right now I've tried this:

```
$webPage = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($webPage);
$div = $doc->getElementById('lga');//this is the id to the div holding the image above the textbox
//echo $webPage;//this displays www.google.com minus the image. I imagine because of the file path
//var_dump($div);//this display "object(DOMElement)#2 (0) { }" and I'm not sure what that means
//echo $div;//this has a server error
```

I'm also looking at simple_html_dom.php trying to figure that out.

Comment: it's working. you got a DOMelement back, which is to be expected. if you want the content of that div, then you'll need $div->innerText or whatever it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
/**
 * Downloads a web page from $url, selects the the element by $id
 * and returns it's xml string representation.
 */
function getElementByIdAsString($url, $id, $pretty = true) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

    if(!$doc) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load $url");
    }

    // Obtain the element
    $element = $doc->getElementById($id);

    if(!$element) {
        throw new Exception("An element with id $id was not found");
    }

    if($pretty) {
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
    }

    // Return the string representation of the element
    return $doc->saveXML($element);
}

// call it:
echo getElementByIdAsString('http://www.google.com', 'lga');
```

Comment: hehe :) happy scraping! ;)